# Is it possible to create an angular directive that does not show up in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would love to be able to create a directive that only outputs the include template to the DOM (not the directive tag).

Basically, so it acts as an include not an element itself. (maybe a directive is not the answer for this). I can accomplish the same thing with a ng-include but the directive syntax of using a tag is more semantic for my purposes.

Example:

```
<btn anchor="true" text="lala"></btn>
```

Outputs:

```
<btn anchor="true" text="lala" class="ng-scope">
    // Contents of included template
</btn>
```

I would like to get rid of this btn tag wrapper.

Here is a full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/XhuS4Kz47aFOdBk4txYT?p=preview

Comment: There is a `replace:true` option in the directive, but it is deprecated and removed, so do not use it (even if you use it you cannot have more than 1 root node in the template you would need to wrap it anyway). Why do you really care about having a wrapper?

Comment: Thanks, yea I looked into that. I care about having the wrapper because it can cause issues with css selectors. (:first-child, :last-child). If you want a bunch of directives in a list for example you can no longer use these selectors on them, you need to style this directive tag instead which is less than ideal.

Comment: You need to fix your selector. You must be using wrong selectors then. Generally you create selectors and rules for your html structure not the opposite.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, the point is that, for my use case, I want to be able to use directives to include html templates and not have to edit or create css based on unnecessary DOM elements.

Comment: compile it yourself then and use `replaceWith()`